# function that finds the most mentions of a given word in a list of strings?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

I want to make a function that takes in a list of strings as an input and, for a given word, returns a tuple containing the string with the most mentions of the given word and the amount of mentions in the string. If multiple strings all have the same max mentions of the word, then the first occurring one out of these strings is returned. **The word is not case-sensitive.**

For example, consider the list:

```
Tomatoes = ['tonight tomatoes grow towards the torchlit tower',
 'the birds fly to the sky',
 'to take the fish to the sea and to tell the tale',
 'to fly to the skies and to taste the clouds']
```

Note that lines 3 and 4 have the most mentions of the word `'to'`.When we put tomatoes into the function with the searchword, `‘to’`, it should look like this:

```
most_word_mentions(Tomatoes, ‘to’)
```

And it should return the third line in a string and the amount of mentions of ‘to’ as a tuple which should look like `(3, 3)`. Although line 3 shares the same amount of word mentions as line 4, it is returned because it occurs first in the list.

**I have created a function that partially achieves what I want, however it fails under specific conditions.**

```
def most_word_mentions(message, word):
    wordcount = []
    for i in range(len(message)):
        message[i] = message[i].lower() #word is not case sensitive
        wordcount.append(((message[i]).count(word)))
    return (wordcount.index(max(wordcount))+1), max(wordcount)
```

If we input `most_word_mentions(Tomatoes, ‘to’)`, then the function fails to output the correct lines and word mentions. Instead, it returns `(1, 6)`. This is because line 1, although it does not contain the explicit word ‘to’, contains many other words with ‘to’ in them. I would like to write a function that accounts for this issue, and that can be applied to similar scenarios. **Could this be done with only for loops and if statements without list comprehension or imports?**

Comment: Do you want to return the line number or the string itself? You mentioned you want to return the "string with the most mentions of the given word" but in your expected output, you are writing (lineNumber, occurances)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I want to return the line number, not the actual string. i.e (3,3) represents line 3 and the amount of word mentions in line 3 repsectively. The output should be a tuple of these two values.

Comment: Is my solution what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses just for loops and if-statements like you required.

```py
def most_word_mentions(list_of_strings, word):
    word = word.lower()
    highest_count = 0
    earliest_index = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        curr_count = 0
        if word in list_of_strings[i].lower():
            curr_count = list_of_strings[i].lower().count(word)
            if curr_count > highest_count:
              if i > earliest_index:
                earliest_index = i
                highest_count = curr_count
    return (earliest_index+1, highest_count)

print(most_word_mentions(Tomatoes, 'to'))
```

Output:

```py
(3,3)
```

Comment: I forgot to account for this case, but if the word does not appear in any of the strings, how would I correct the output to (0,0) instead of (1,0)?

Comment: Append the target `word` to `list_of_strings`. Now we will _always_ find it. Adjust the output to be (0, 0) in the case where we got all the way to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I started on, which follows a slightly different idea:

```py
def mostCommon(word,sentences):
  sentencecount={} # keep track of sentences and occurance in sentence
  for item in sentences: #iterate through sentences
    lowcasesentence=item.lower().split() #make sentence lowercase, and split so that there is a list with each word of the sentence
    sentencecount[item]=lowcasesentence.count(word) #call the method "count", which counts all occurances in a list. Append that to sentencecount
  return(sentencecount) # return sentences as a dictionary with count as their value.
```

Instead of iterating through each letter combination, you should split the sentence into words and count that. Note that my function gives all the sentences back, not just the one with the mostest word count.

Comment: Thank you for describing your steps. I wasn't sure which way would be most efficient for solving the problem, so it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
def most_word_mentions(message, word):
    word = word.lower()
    line = 0
    most = 0
    for i in range(len(message)):
        count = 0
        for w in message[i].lower().split():
            if word == w:
                count += 1
        if count > most:
            line = i + 1
            most = count
    return (line, most)
```